# How to use interceptors in java tool?

Tags: java, interceptor

Is it possible to use Interceptors without an application server, eg in just a command line tool?

I tried the following, but I don't see any output:

```
import javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke;
import javax.interceptor.InvocationContext;

public class PerformanceInterceptor {
    @AroundInvoke
    Object measureTime(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("STARTING"); //I don't see this
    }
}


class MyTest() {
    @Interceptors(PerformanceInterceptor.class)
    void execute() {
        System.out.println("RUNNING"); //I see this
    }
}
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: I think they only work for EJBs, not for "plain" Java classes.

Answer (score 0):

Check with this example : http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/java-ee-ejb-interceptors-tutorial-and-example. BTW, nice Java EE 6 feature.

Without EJB and Java EE staff use Dynamic Proxy in Java.

Comment: And how does that answer the question "*use [..] **without** an application server*"?